# Generating random dots within an outer circle that have a certain distance

Tags: python, math, random

I'm currently really stuck with some of my code and I can't seem to find the issue. Here is what I am trying to do:
I have a big outer circle in which I want to display smaller dots. These dots should be randomly distributed but should not overlap, thus they should have a minimum distance to each other.

What I have tried is to first randomly generate a point, check wether it is in the outer circle and if it is, append it to the final list of dot positions. Then another point is created, checked if in circle and then it should be checked if the dot has a minimum distance to the other dot(s) in the final list.

However, I seem to have some issues with my code as it will not run through whenever I set the required distances higher than 1. I have changed multiple things, but I cannot make it work.

Does anyone have an idea about what the problem might be?

Here's what I have been trying:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import math

#Variables
radiusOC = 57
size_obj = 7
required_dist = 5
no_stimuli = 3


def CreatePos(radiusOC, size_obj, required_dist, no_stimuli):
    final_list = []
    def GenRandPos(radiusOC,size_obj):
        """
        Takes the radius of the outer circle and generates random dots within this radius. Then checks if the the dots are located 
        within the outer circle.
        """
        while True:
            xPos = random.randint(-radiusOC,radiusOC)
            yPos = random.randint(-radiusOC,radiusOC)
        
            # check if in Circle 
            on_circle = (xPos- 0)**2 + (yPos-0)**2
            if (radiusOC-size_obj)**2 >= on_circle:
                print("Still in circle",on_circle, xPos, yPos )
                position = [xPos, yPos]
                break
            else:
                print("Not in circle",on_circle, xPos, yPos )
                continue
                
        return position


    def CheckSurrounding(position, final_list, required_dist): 
        """
        Takes dot positions that are in the visual field, the list of positions, and the distances dots are required to have from each other. 
        It is checked if there are dots close by or not.  
        """
        X1 = position[0]
        Y1 = position[1]
        dist_list = []
        for elem in final_list:
            for i in elem: 
                X2 = elem[0]
                Y2 = elem[1]
                dist = math.sqrt((X1-X2)**2 + (Y1-Y2)**2)
                dist_list.append(dist)
                
        if all(dist_list) >= required_dist: 
            return position
            
        else:
            return None

    # append the first dot to the list
    position = GenRandPos(radiusOC, size_obj)
    final_list.append(position)

    # now append the rest of the dots if they have a certain distance to each other
    while len(final_list) < no_stimuli: 
        position = GenRandPos(radiusOC, size_obj)

        if CheckSurrounding(position, final_list, required_dist)  != None: 
            position = CheckSurrounding(position, final_list, required_dist)
            final_list.append(position)

        else: 
            continue
    
    return final_list


´´´
```

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
if all(dist_list) >= required_dist:
```

`all(dist_list)` will be either `True` or `False`, which is numerically equivalent to either 1 or 0. If `required_dist` is greater than 1 the inequality will never be satisfied. I think that you intended this to be

```
if all(dist_list >= required_dist):
```

but this will not work since you cannot compare a list `dist_list` to a number `required_dist`. To fix it, convert `dist_list` to a numpy array:

```
if np.all(np.array(dist_list) >= required_dist):
```

By the way, the random points you are selecting will always have integer coordinates since you are using `random.randint()`, I am not sure if this is intentional.

The whole code can be made more efficient by using numpy arrays. For example:

```
import numpy as np

def CreatePos(radiusOC, size_obj, required_dist, no_stimuli):
    final_list = []

    def GenRandPos(radiusOC, size_obj):
        """
        Takes the radius of the outer circle and generates 
        random dots within this radius. Then checks if the dots are 
        located within the outer circle.
        """

        while True:
            position = (2 * np.random.random(2) - 1) * radiusOC
            # check if in Circle
            if (radiusOC - size_obj)**2 >= (position**2).sum():
                return position

    def CheckSurrounding(position, final_list, required_dist):
        """
        Takes dot positions that are in the visual field, 
        the list of positions, and the distances dots are 
        required to have from each other. 
        It is checked if there are dots close by or not.  
        """

        final_arr = np.array(final_list)
        dist = ((np.array(final_list) - position)**2).sum(axis=1)
        if np.all(np.array(dist) >= required_dist**2):
            return position

    # append the first dot to the list
    position = GenRandPos(radiusOC, size_obj)
    final_list.append(position)

    # now append the rest of the dots if they have a certain distance to each other
    while len(final_list) < no_stimuli:
        position = GenRandPos(radiusOC, size_obj)
        if CheckSurrounding(position, final_list, required_dist) is not None:
            final_list.append(position)

    return final_list
```

Note that this returns a list of points with coordinates given by floats, not integers.

Sample usage:

```
#Variables
radiusOC = 57
size_obj = 7
required_dist = 3
no_stimuli = 400

final_list  = np.array(CreatePos(radiusOC, size_obj, required_dist, no_stimuli))
```

Plot the resulting points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.scatter(f[:, 0], f[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image: dots in a circle]

I would add a condition in the final `while` loop so it can break if a new point cannot be found after some number of attempts. Otherwise, it may end up running indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out a way to estimate the max number of points given the distance. This can be extrapolated from the circle packing problem. https://planetcalc.com/7473/ I will comment if I have an easy check to do.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def random_in_circle(num_points=1000, R=1, min_dist=0.2):
    assert min_dist < R, "Min distance between points must be smaller than the radius of outer circle"
    assert R / (2 ** (num_points - 1)) < min_dist, "Min dist is too large"
    points = []
    while len(points) < num_points:
        a = np.random.rand() * 2 * np.pi # random angle
        r = R * np.random.rand() # random radius
        point = r * np.array([np.cos(a), np.sin(a)])
        if len(points) == 0:
            points.append(point)
        elif np.all(cdist([point], points) > min_dist):
            points.append(point)
    return np.vstack(points)

points = random_in_circle(num_points=1000, min_dist=0.01)
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]